# Eclipse plugin dependency on SWT classes not being resolved

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have an eclipse plugin project which uses some swt objects, eg -

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
```

When I try to compile it with the 'Target Platform' set to 'Running Platform (Active)', it compiles fine and I dont need to import any swt specific plugins.

However, I created a target platform with Eclipse 3.6.0 and if I set it as the active platform the project has compile errors wherever swt classes are used and cannot resolve them.

Which plugin should I add a dependency to, to resolve these errors?

I tried adding 'org.eclipse.swt' but that does not seem to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. I was trying to compile against a 32 bit target platform on a 64 bit OS, so the filters were not matching the SWT libraries until I set them manually from the target platform preferences.

Comment: Oh, God, thank you very much!  I was going nuts with dozens of not resolved SWT components erros.  You saved my day.

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Target Platform -> Edit -> Environment -> set Architecture to "x86". worked for me

Comment: I have the same problem but the solution did not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. In my case, I had a missing dependency and I asked Eclipse to locate the plugin for me.

After the plugin was found on some p2 site, I saw "Resetting Target Platform" in the progress view.

After that, a lot of plugins were broken. Checking the target platform (Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform -> Edit), the field "Architecture" had changed from `x86_64` to `x86`.

Changing the value back and clicking on "Finish" did reset the TP once more and the errors went away.

Comment: How does one ask Eclipse to find missing dependencies?

Comment: Use the context menu in the "Problems View" or Ctrl+1.

Comment: I have this problem but my target platform was already set to `x86_64`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I needed to add external jars corresponding to the SWT libraries to my build path. Moreover, I needed to add ones specific to my platform (Windows).

I added the following jar to my project build path:

```
$USER/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.swt_3.106.1.v20170926-0519.jar
```

Comment: Why did you add the same JAR twice? Your solution is probably wrong and just hides a mistake you made elsewhere. You really need to check your target platform. When the plugin is in the target platform, Eclipse should be able to figure everything out.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this problem on Mac M1 arm processor: I ran into this problem when upgraded eclipse to use arm versions of jdk, etc.  To fix, had to manually change the target to aarch64 for eclipse via eclipse/preferences/plugin development.  The default was incorrect and was x86 target.